# как в js получить ссылку с помощью data-url=""

Tags: javascript

как в js получить ссылку с помощью data-url=""

---

в моём случае в скрипте есть аналог для получении основной ссылке

`url: iUrl, ->>> href="'+iUrl+'"`

а в html `data-url="{$link$}"`

---

так мне нужно в тот же js использовать дополнительную ссылку
в html `data-trailer_url="{$trailer-link$}"`

а в js trailer_url: trUrl, ->>> href="'+trUrl+'"

как реализовать ???могу показать кусок из js

```
$('body').on('click','.js-trl',function(){
        var iUrl = $(this).data('url'), iThis = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: iUrl,
            beforeSend: function() {},           
            success: function(data) {
                $('body').append('<div class="tr-overlay"></div><div class="tr-box"><div class="tr-video video-box"></div></div>');
                $(".tr-video").append($('#trailer-place', data).html());
                $(".tr-box").append('<div class="tr-btm fx-row fx-middle icon-left"><a href="'+iUrl+'" class="btn js-trl-scroll"><span class="fa fa-play-circle"></span>Смотреть онлайн</a></div>');
                $(".tr-box").prepend('<div class="tr-header fx-row fx-middle"><div class="fx-1">Трейлер</div><span class="fa fa-times"></span></div>');
                $(".tr-box, .tr-overlay").fadeIn('200');
                if (iThis.hasClass("have-trailers")) {
                   $(".tr-btm").append('<a href="/trailers/" class="btn"><span class="fa fa-folder-open-o"></span>Все трейлеры</a>');
                };
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно и так

```js
console.log( document.querySelector('[data-url]').dataset.url );
```

```html
<div data-url='site.com'>url</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

например так:

```
var url = document.getElementById("ID_ELEMENT").getAttribute('data-url');
```